# Very Unusual User Login PHP Session Issue

Tags: php, session

I have created a basic PHP login system for a website. So far, the only real feature members can participate in is a made from scratch forum.

For some reason, the session variables are not lining up with the proper user. For example:

1. User John logs in. Everything is fine. He posts to a forum and his username is attributed to his post.
2. User Jane logs in. Things get weird. When Jane posts to a forum, John's username is attributed to the post. Likewise, when John posts after Jane has logged in, Jane's username is attributed to the post.

I have no idea why or how this could happen.

-----------Requested Code-----------------------------

Here is the login code, I am assuming the problem must be somewhere here:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$citizen_email = $_POST['form_email'];
$citizen_password = $_POST['form_password'];
//

// Connect To Database
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "notreal", "notreal", "notreal");
// Create & Submit Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM citizens WHERE citizen_email='$citizen_email' AND citizen_password='$citizen_password'";
$query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_result);
if ($query_num_rows > 0) {
while ($query_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$citizen_name = $query_array['citizen_name'];
$citizen_id = $query_array['citizen_id'];
}
$_SESSION["citizen_id"] = $citizen_id;
$_SESSION["citizen_name"] = $citizen_name;

$sqlOnlineCitizen = "INSERT INTO online_citizens VALUES ('$citizen_id', now(), now())";
$onlineCitizenGo = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlOnlineCitizen);
$content = "<p>Welcome to Sachap $citizen_name. <a href=\"http://nationsimulationgame.com/nation/index.php\">Click here</a> to continue.</p>";
} else {
$content = "<p>The email/password combination you provided did not match any citizenship records. You can <a href=\"customs_login.php\">try again</a> or <a href=\"#\">recover your password.</a></p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can we see the code? It helps us to help you.

Comment: `I have no idea why or how this could happen.` We can not tell you, too, without the code.

Comment: This could happen if your assigning a session variable with username like I suspect then when you logout your not unsetting/nulling it, some code of your basic login/logout would help narrow it down

Comment: This question is too general to answer with a specific answer. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Computers don't do unusual things. They do exactly what they are told. Since PHP is very mature the only thing that is unusual is you.  Better to accept it and add some code so we can find where you made a mistake ;)

Comment: Hi Derek, code has been added.

Comment: un-related but extremely important. I see sql injection, plain text passwords in db, possible multiple users returned from login, use `LIMIT 1` in  the query, appart from that i think your error is in the logout

Comment: Yes, the SQL Injection & md5'ing the passwords will be fixed ASAP. Will try the LIMIT 1. As for the logout, there is no logout script created just yet. It does destroy the session after ten minutes of inactivity however.

Answer (score -1):

Are these real users or test accounts?  Is it possible they have the same email and password but different names?

Comment: Both of these area real users that registered once we moved off of localhost. We used different email addresses and passwords. Somehow our session information is being swapped.